# jQuery - update function with deprecated toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to update my website to jQuery 1.10 but I use a function with the deprecated `toggle()`.

I remember, I was having a hard time to make this function works in first time, does it exists a function that could replace the `toggle()` without changing all the code.

I am not a jQuery expert and help would be appreciated.

css:

```
fieldset.collapsed * {
    display: none;
}

fieldset.collapsed h2, fieldset.collapsed {
    display: block !important;
}

fieldset.collapsed h2 {
    background-image: url(../img/nav-bg.gif);
    background-position: bottom left;
    color: #999;
}

fieldset.collapsed .collapse-toggle {
    background: transparent;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

jquery:

```
var sPath=window.location.pathname;
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        function show () { // Show
            $(this).text(gettext("Hide"))
                .closest("fieldset")
                .removeClass("collapsed")
                .trigger("show.fieldset", [$(this).attr("id")]);
            window.localStorage.setItem($(this).attr("id"), true);
        }
        function hide () { // Hide
            $(this).text(gettext("Show"))
                .closest("fieldset")
                .addClass("collapsed")
                .trigger("hide.fieldset", [$(this).attr("id")]);
            window.localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr("id"))
            return false;
        }
        // Add anchor tag for Show/Hide link
        $("fieldset.collapse").each(function (i, elem) {
            // Don't hide if fields in this fieldset have errors
            key = 'fieldsetcollapser' + i + sPath;
            if (typeof (window.localStorage) != 'undefined') {
                var item = $(elem)
                .addClass("collapsed")
                .find("h2")
                .first()
                .append(' (<a id=' +
                        key +
                        ' " class="collapse-toggle" href="#">' +
                        gettext("Show") +
                        '</a>)'
                ).find('a');
                if (window.localStorage.getItem(key)) {
                    //alert('show')
                    show.apply(item);
                    $(item).toggle(hide, show);
                }else {
                    if ($("ul.errorlist").length >0) {
                      //alert('yo show')
                      show.apply(item);
                      $(item).toggle(hide, show);
                  }else{
                     $(item).toggle(show, hide);
                     //alert("hide")
                }
                }

            } else {
                throw "window.localStorage, not defined";
            }
        });
    });
```

**EDITED:**[See how it works here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3sdj/1/) (working with jQuery 1.6)

Comment: Replace it with a single click event that instead of adding or removing a class, simply toggles the class.

Comment: I would seriously consider renaming your "hide" and "show" to prevent confusion from $(this).hide() and this.hide()

Comment: Can you please post your CSS for ".collapsed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The reason that the .toggle() function was deprecated was because of confusion just like this!**

What's going on is that your code is calling (on an alternating basis) your own internal "hide" and "show" functions.  The `.toggle(hide,show)` call takes care of that for you.

However, inside of your hide() and show() functions, you're not actually *hiding* or *showing* anything. What you're doing is *adding or removing a class*, which may or may not hide or show something.

**The solution**

The only solution to *alternatively call these two functions* is to change the 'click' event each time one of those functions is called.

At the bottom of your show() code, you need to add:

```
$(this).one("click", hide);
```

At the bottom of your hide() code, you need to add:

```
$(this).one("click", show);
```

Finally, you need to replace your calls to .toggle() with these calls:

```
$(item).one("click", hide); // replaces $(item).toggle(hide,show);
$(item).one("click", show); // replaces $(item).toggle(show,hide);
```

**Why not .is(":visible")?**

Quite simply, the class that you are adding/removing is the "collapsed" class.  This class *does not actually hide* the $(item).  Because of this the $(this).is(":visible") will **always** be true!

Clearly, that won't work.

Here is a demonstration that illustrates the point: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Dwp/)

---

**Fully in code**

For those who like to read code instead of words:

```
function firstEvent() {   // e.g. "hide"
    //First event code
    $(item).one("click", secondEvent); 
}
function secondEvent() {  // e.g. "show"
    //Second event code
    $(item).one("click", firstEvent); 
}

$(item).one("click", firstEvent); // replaces $(item).toggle(firstEvent, secondEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace your instances with an if statement

```
$(item).click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
       $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Here is a demo of my above code working using a `p` element and an `img`.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/8TFFx/

You could also do it by using CSS/Jquery

```
$('p').click(function(){
  if ($('img').is(':visible')) {
       $('img').css("display","none");
    }
    else {
        $('img').css("display","block");
    }
});
```

Comment: wrong version of .toggle. show hide .toggle is not deprecated, he's using the click event toggle in his code which is deprecated.

Comment: [This .toggle() that was deprecated and removed](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: Same logic applies, i updated my answer.

Comment: what's with the down vote? He is trying to show/hide on click, my code does that

Comment: Probably was a remnant from your original answer, which was absolutely wrong.

Comment: Also, the .hide() you are calling is the jQuery version.  The version it should be calling is the event handler from the question.

Comment: This seems like a good logical approach. Why did `.toggle` get deprecated?

Comment: His hide/show events do not make the item hidden.  They add the class "collapsed".  This just won't work

Comment: @TheApptracker There are two .toggle() functions.  One is used to show/hide something.  The other is used to perform round-robin calls to functions based on click events.  A bit too confusing.  This code above does the second.

Comment: Here's why it won't work:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Dwp/)